# Can't find proper criteria to update document in mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have followed model stored in mongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : "some_table_name",
"content" : [{
  "id" : "1",
  "locname" : "KKH"
}, {
  "id" : "2",
  "locname" : "Singapore National Eye Centre"
}]
}
```

I try to find criteria to update 2nd element (id=2) aka add new String.

`"new_element" : "foo"`

So new view should be:

```
{
    "_id" : "some_table_name",
"content" : [{
  "id" : "1",
  "locname" : "KKH"
}, {
  "id" : "2",
 "locname" : "Singapore National Eye Centre"
  "new_element" : "foo" 
}]
}
```

**Form PHP**

When I try to find 2nd node by id I use:

```
$array = $collection_bios2->findOne(
                array("_id" => "some_table_name", "content.id" => "2"),
                array("_id" => 0, "content.$" => 1)
        );
```

But when I try to update it, new node enters under `content`:

```
$newdata = array('$set' => array("new_element" => "foo"));
$collection_bios2->update(
                         array("_id" => "some_table_name", "content.id" => "2"),                      
                         $newdata
                         );
```

I get:

```
{
    "_id" : "some_table_name",
"content" : [{
  "id" : "1",
  "locname" : "KKH"
}, {
  "id" : "2",
  "locname" : "Singapore National Eye Centre"
}],
"new_element" : "foo"
}
```

Whats wrong in my implementation?

Please, help,

Maxim

Comment: You need to use the positional operator like so: `array('$set'=>array('content.$.new_element':'foo'))`

Comment: Great! it works, please, paste it in answer to allow me to vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the positional operator here:

```
array('$set'=>array('content.$.new_element':'foo'))
```

You can read more about it here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/